# Cannot Understand a Short simple Algorithm in Perl

Tags: algorithm, perl, file

I never worked with Perl, that's why I need a little help to understand the following code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<@ARGV; $i++) {
    open F, $ARGV[$i];
    while (<F>) {
        chomp;
        ($y,@x) = split;
        print $y;
        map { print " *$_ $i$_" } @x;
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

I see that it iterates over a file(per line?),
and then `while(<F>)`, meaning not empty?
The chomp strips the string from newlines, spaces etc.

The concept in general of perl confuses me, can anyone explain the example to me?

Comment: Check perldoc split, inspecting variables is also helpful.

Comment: As per [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527843/frustratingly-easy-domain-adaptation-explanation) the code comes from the paper *[Frustratingly Easy Domain Adaptation](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~hal/docs/daume07easyadapt.pdf)* by Hal Daumé.

Answer (score 5):

What's going on with the `while` in particular - and warrants a bit more explanation.

Perl has a concept of an implict variable `$_` - this variable is set to the current thing within each of the loop constructs `for`, `while`.

When you do this for a `while` loop, what you *actually* get is:

```
while ( defined $_ = <$FH> ) {
```

This means it reads a line from the file handle, and *tests the result* of the operation. If you hit EOF then the while loop ends.

But through the loop, you have access to `$_` - and both `chomp` and `split` act on this by default.

So you're doing:

```
 while ( defined $_ = <$FH> ) { 
     chomp ( $_ ); #strip trailing whitespace;
     ( $x, @y ) = split ( ' ', $_ );
```

What's happening at this point is you're assigning one list to another. So the list generated by 'split' is assigned - in order - to `( $x, @y )` - making `$x` the first element, and `@y` everything else.

That `map` line is misusing `map` - and as such it's not too suprising that it's a bit confusing.

What `map` is *supposed* to do is apply a transform to a list and output another list.

So you might do:

```
my @uppercase = map { uc } @list_of_lowercase;
```

And the list of lower case turns into a list of upper case, because the `uc` function is run on each element.

By not assigning an output though, it's a big warning sign that what they should really be using is `for`

```
print "$y ";
foreach my $value ( @x ) {
   print "*$value $i$value";
}
print "\n";
```

(I tend to prefer using `foreach` rather than `for` when you're naming your things, but they're identical really).

Answer (score 3):

That Perl isn't very well written. This equivalent may help you

I think everything is prety much self-explanatory. Take a look at [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/) for descriptions of individual operators

It may help to know that `my ($first, @rest) = split` splits each record on whitespace, and puts the first field into `$first` and the rest into array `@rest`. Also, the string `" *$field $i$field"` just builds a string with the indicated variables replaced by their values

```
for my $i ( 0 .. $#ARGV ) {

    open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[$i]
            or die qq{Unable to open "$ARGV[$i]" for input: $!};

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;
        my ($first, @rest) = split;
        print $first;
        for my $field ( @rest ) {
            print " *$field $i$field";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In terms of functionality, this is a fairly trivial text tranformation. It loops across a set of files and replaces the entries with a repeat of the elements in the tail of each line first with an asterisk, then with the (zero-based) index of the file prefixed to the field. For example, given two files containing

```
a b
c d e f
```

and

```
K L M
N O P Q
```

the output will be

```
a *b 0b
c *d 0d *e 0e *f 0f
K *L 1L *M 1M
N *O 1O *P 1P *Q 1Q
```

A much simpler `sed` or Awk script could easily be devised.

```
i=0
for file in list of filenames; do
    sed "/ \([^ ]*\)/ *\1 $i\1/g" "$file"
    ((i++))
done
```

or this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe '++$i if (defined $prev && $prev ne $ARGV); $prev = $ARGV; s/\s+(\S+)/ *$1 $i$1/g' list of filenames
```

Based on a cursory reading of the paper, I'm guessing that the expected input is a token and its analysis; then, apparently, the generated asterisk-prefixed analysis is the "general" analysis, and the number-prefixed analysis is the one specific to this input file (i.e. corpus, i.e. source or target). But take this with a huge grain of salt.

Comment: "tripleee how this code can work beyond text features. I dont get the asterisk part.

Comment: @JoseRamon It's just a text transformation, you probably have a subsequent processing step which decides what the asterisk means and what to do with it.  It's several months since I posted this answer so I have no recollection of the referenced paper any longer.